# Merge alternate lines from two files

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, paste

File1:

```
.tid.setnr := 1123 
.tid.setnr := 3345 
.tid.setnr := 5431
.tid.setnr := 89323
```

File2:

```
.tid.info := 12
.tid.info := 3
.tid.info := 44
.tid.info := 60
```

Output file:

```
.tid.info := 12
.tid.setnr := 1123
.tid.info := 3
.tid.setnr := 3345
.tid.info := 44
.tid.setnr := 5431
.tid.info := 60
.tid.setnr := 89323
```

Comment: Please _always_ mention your operating system. A lot of the standard tools behave differently on the different OSs so we need to know what you're using.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using [`paste`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html):

```
paste -d \\n file2 file1
```

Answer (score 5):

Another awk solution:

```
awk '{print; getline < "file1"; print}' file2
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`paste` solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210179) is the most portable and most efficient. I'm only mentioning this alternative in case you prefer its behaviour in the case where the two files don't have the same number of lines:

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed Rfile1 file2
```

If `file1` has fewer lines than `file2`, then when `file1` is exhausted, `sed` will not output anything for it (as opposed to empty lines for `paste`).

If `file1` has more lines than `file2`, then those extra lines will be discarded (as opposed to printing empty lines for `file2` with `paste`).

```
$ paste a b
1       a
2       b
3
4
$ paste -d \\n a b
1
a
2
b
3

4

$ sed Rb a
1
a
2
b
3
4
$ sed Ra b
a
1
b
2
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk` (`gawk`, `nawk`, `mawk`):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {x[FNR]=$0;next} {print x[FNR]"\n"$0}' file2 file1 > outputfile
```

- `NR==FNR {x[FNR]=$0;next}`: `NR==FNR` is matched only if the current record number is equal to the current file record number (hence it's matched only while processing the first file): stores the currently processed record into the array `x` at an index equal to the current file record number and skips the current record
- `{print x[FNR]"\n"$0}`: prints the content of the array `x` at an index equal to the current file record number followed by a newline and by the content of the current record

```bsh
~/tmp$ cat file1
.tid.setnr := 1123
.tid.setnr := 3345
.tid.setnr := 5431
.tid.setnr := 89323
~/tmp$ cat file2
.tid.info := 12
.tid.info := 3
.tid.info := 44
.tid.info := 60
~/tmp$ awk 'NR==FNR {x[FNR]=$0;next} {print x[FNR]"\n"$0}' file2 file1
.tid.info := 12
.tid.setnr := 1123
.tid.info := 3
.tid.setnr := 3345
.tid.info := 44
.tid.setnr := 5431
.tid.info := 60
.tid.setnr := 89323
```

Comment: It's giving the output but not exactly the same what I wanted. tid.info lines are coming after tid.setnr lines in my output file.

Comment: @Nainita That's what you're showing in your example output.

Comment: @Nainita Anyway to switch the order of the output you can just switch `file1` and `file2` in the command.

Comment: Yes...I have done the same but it was printing the exactly as before . after printing tid.setnr then it was priting tid.info.

Comment: @Nainita No, it doesn't. Try again: `awk 'NR==FNR {x[FNR]=$0;next} {print x[FNR]"\n"$0}' file1 file2`.

Comment: @kos - if it matters, most of Nainita's other questions have been targeted at a Solaris system. Is it possible your script uses some non-standard syntax which might result as he/she indicates?

Comment: @mikeserv Not that it seems. `FNR` is a `gawk` / `nawk` feature, so if it works it means he/she's not using the original `awk` which lacks it, and if it works one way it should work the other way around also. Unless he/she's using something other than the original `awk`, `gawk` or `nawk` which might lack something else.

Comment: @Nainita Can you provide the version of `awk` you're using?

Comment: @kos - it's probably `mawk` - it's Solaris.

Comment: @mikeserv it is the OP's responsibility to mention the OS. If they don't, it's not up to us to go search the OP's history and guess it. We don't know how many machines they have or if they all use Solaris or what. All we can do is provide answers based on the information we have. If that's not good enough for the OP, it will be for the next person who stumbles upon the answer.

Comment: @terdon - I guess, but isn't this site all about the OS?

Comment: @mikeserv which is why I left a comment _to the OP_ asking them to clarify. My point is that if the OP can't be bothered to tell us what OS they're using, we can't be expected to guess it from their history. Nor should we, there's no reason to assume they only use one.

Comment: @terdon - they posted on *Unix and Linux* - it's one or the other - how specific should you have to be? And I didn't make that assumption, eiither. I was just letting kos know, I couldn't upvote the answer again, but I saw the comments here and so I let kos know what I did. What's wrong with that? As to guessing - is it not a guess already if your answer is prohibitive in some way, or limited by OS?

Comment: @mikeserv However since I was at it I tried `mawk` also, and it runs on it as well. Anyway being reasonable I can't see why it shouldn't work *just* the other way around (i.e. *just* by switching files). It's not that `awk` cares about the input, lines are lines. If something wasn't supported by his version it would have just broke the first time. Way more easily, simply OP did a mistake switching the input files in the arguments.

Comment: @kos - sweet. That rules that out. Probably was an input error. I still can't upvote you again, though. Sorry.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks for the first one. I'll settle for it

Comment: @mikeserv I'm not saying you did anything wrong, I'm annoyed at the OP, not you. As you well know, there are important differences both between Linux and Unix and between the various Unices. That's why it's important the OP tell us which they are using.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest solution is given below.

```
cat file1 >> file2
```

or

```
cat file2 >> file1
```

Comment: sachin, read the question again; this appends the content of one file to the content of another file. It does not merge the files _alternating_ the lines (so one line from `file1` then one line from `file2` and so on...)